# regarding file copying in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, permissions, filesystem

i have to replace my hard disk drive (not a usb type HDD, 500gb) so i have backed up content to some other hardisk (not a usb HDD, 80gb). Then i brought a new HDD also installed ubuntu 12.04 & windowns XP

after installation i have connected my new hard disk (500gb) to computer having 80gb HDD. and copied all the files to /home/myname/backup after copying i have removed HDD and placed in my computer , but i was not able to see backup folder , set permission to 777 (with -R), but i was only able to see files while i was booted with live cd as the owner of the file was ubuntu live cd

question 
how can i access my files without live cd

solution worked for me
copyed files to NTFS / FAT partition in my hard disk ,

FOR MY KNDOWLEDGE I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW AN ALTERNATE SOLUTION.

Answer (score 0):

if your backup folder on the hard drive is "bak", and your ubuntu username is "deepu" do this:

```
sudo chown -R deepu:deepu /path/to/bak
```

that should make all the files yours